# How to get link of client's request on a socket web server?

Tags: python, html, sockets, web, server

I'm trying to create a basic local web server using python sockets. You input a url into your browser (i.e. `http://localhost/mysite.html`), and it gives you back the requested file.

```
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost', 8080))
s.listen(1)

while True:
    try:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        # Get the url and attempt to open the file
    except KeyBoardInterrupt:
        break
s.close()
```

I can obviously receive data using c (client socket), but I don't need that, I want the link that it's requesting from the server. I have read some of socket's documentation, and cannot find anything relevant to my question.

Comment: Do you need to get requested URL?

Comment: Reading socket documentation is not sufficient. You need to implement the application layer protocol HTTP on the socket.  For this you need to implement [the HTTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110), which is fairly complex. At a minimum make yourself familiar with the basics of the HTTP protocol on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) and follow the examples there.

Comment: @AndreyIvanov Yes, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: Check out http.server library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html
`requestline` property of `http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly obvious in hindsight but unintuitive, socket.recv() actually does this for you.

```
clientMsg = clientSocket.recv(1024).decode().split()
print(clientMsg)
```

Output:

```
GET /mysite.html HTTP/1.1 # The file being requested by browser
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A- 
Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
# Other html protocol stuff excluded
```